# termset based breadcrumb in SharePoint 2016

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, breadcrumb, portalsitemapprovider

How to get SharePoint breadcrumb based on Managed Navigation rather than Structural Navigation in SharePoint 2016 onpremises? Can it be done by providing an OOTB Sitemapprovider?

Do we need to go for custom Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Just activate the publishing feature. For more info. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/overview-of-managed-navigation

Comment: I want breadcrumb navigation. Not top navigation bar.